# HTML alignment off in Outlook 2013

Tags: html, css, outlook, alignment

I have this "infobox" being sent in an email that is rendering well across most clients except for Outlook 2013. The text in the bottom row of the table is shifted when received by Outlook 2013?

Any ideas?

Here's my code:

```
<!-- Start Info Box -->
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="532" style="border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: none;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="padding-top: 20px;">
                            <img src="http://purolatorforsmallbusiness.com/content/acquisition/onboarding/infotab-top.png" alt="" height="7" width="532" style="border: 0;outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; display: block;">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: none;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="3" style="border-left:2px solid #00A9E0;border-right:2px solid #00A9E0;text-align: center; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #001996; font-size: 20px; font-weight: 700; line-height: 22px; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 10px;">
                                        Have a Q that needs an A?
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td width="250" height="30" style="padding-left:10px;border-left:2px solid #00A9E0;font-weight: 700; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height: 15px;color:black;vertical-align:bottom;padding-bottom:10px; padding-left: 25px;">
                                            Shipping help:
                                        </td>
                                        <td valign="bottom" align="center" width="2" rowspan="3" style="padding-left: 30px; padding-right: 30px;">
                                        <img src="http://purolatorforsmallbusiness.com/content/acquisition/onboarding/vertical-line.png" alt="|" height="80%" width="1" style="border: 0;outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; display: block;"></td>
                                        <td width="250" height="30" style="padding-left:10px;border-right:2px solid #00A9E0;font-weight: 700; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height: 15px;color:black;vertical-align:bottom;padding-bottom:10px;">
                                            Account questions:
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style='padding-left:25px;border-left:2px solid #00A9E0;vertical-align:top;' class="temp-borders">
                                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse; -ms-text-size-adjust: none;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; padding-bottom: 20px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="padding-right: 5px; padding-bottom: 1px;">
                                                <img src="http://purolatorforsmallbusiness.com/content/acquisition/onboarding/phone.png" alt="Phone" height="13" width="14" style="border: 0;outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; display: block;">
                                                </td>
                                                <td valign="bottom" style="font-weight: 400; line-height: 18px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; padding-bottom: 1px;">
                                                    1&nbsp;888&nbsp;SHIP-123
                                                </td>
                                                <td style="padding-right: 5px; padding-bottom: 1px;">
                                                <img src="http://purolatorforsmallbusiness.com/content/acquisition/onboarding/chat.png" alt="Chat" height="13" width="14" style="border: 0;outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; display: block;">
                                                </td>
                                                <td valign="bottom" style="font-weight: 400; line-height: 18px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; padding-bottom: 1px;">
                                                <a style="text-decoration:none; color: #000000;" href="http://purolator.force.com/PreChat?chatLanguage=EN" target="_blank">Live&nbsp;Chat</a>
                                                </td>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="padding-right: 5px; padding-bottom: 1px;">
                                                    <img src="http://purolatorforsmallbusiness.com/content/acquisition/onboarding/email.png" alt="Email" height="10" width="14" style="border: 0;outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; display: block;">
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td valign="bottom" style="font-weight: 400; line-height: 18px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; padding-bottom: 1px;">
                                                    <a style="text-decoration:none; color: #000000;" href="mailto:customer.care@purolator.com" target="_blank">E-mail us</a>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td style="padding-right: 5px; padding-bottom: 1px;">
                                                <img src="http://purolatorforsmallbusiness.com/content/acquisition/onboarding/twitter.png" alt="Email" height="11" width="16" style="border: 0;outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; display: block;">
                                                </td>
                                                <td valign="bottom" style="font-weight: 400; line-height: 18px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; padding-bottom: 1px;">
                                                <a style="text-decoration:none; color: #000000;" href="https://twitter.com/PurolatorHelp/" target="_blank">Tweet us</a>
                                                </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                        </td>
                                        <td style='padding-left:10px;border-right:2px solid #00A9E0;vertical-align:top;'>
                                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: none;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; padding-bottom: 20px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="padding-right: 5px; padding-bottom: 1px;">
                                                <img src="http://purolatorforsmallbusiness.com/content/acquisition/onboarding/phone.png" alt="Phone" height="13" width="14" style="border: 0;outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; display: block;">
                                                </td>
                                                <td valign="bottom" style="font-weight: 400; line-height: 18px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; padding-bottom: 1px;">
                                                    1&nbsp;855&nbsp;711&nbsp;7277&nbsp;(PBRP)
                                                </td>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="padding-right: 5px; padding-bottom: 1px;">
                                                    <img src="http://purolatorforsmallbusiness.com/content/acquisition/onboarding/email.png" alt="Email" height="10" width="14" style="border: 0;outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; display: block;">
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td valign="bottom" style="font-weight: 400; mso-line-height-rule:exactly; line-height: 18px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px;">
                                                    <a style="text-decoration:none; color: #000000;" href="mailto:businessrewards@purolator.com" target="_blank">E-mail us</a>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: none;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; border-left: 2px solid #00a9e0; border-right: 2px solid #00a9e0; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 1px; mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: none;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; margin: 0; font-size: 1px; mso-line-height-rule:exactly; line-height:1px; height:1px;">&nbsp;


                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="mso-line-height-rule:exactly;line-height:7px;height:7px;">
                            <img src="http://purolatorforsmallbusiness.com/content/acquisition/onboarding/infotab-bottom.png" alt="" height="7" width="532" style="border: 0;outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; display: block;">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td height="20">&nbsp;

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <!-- End Info Box -->
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the issue was a validation error. You had the closing TR for "Live chat" below the closing TR for "Tweet us". Once moved to correct position works fine.

The other possibility is if you are talking about Outlook 2013 when viewed on a larger DPI screen (https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/dpi_scaling_in_outlook_2007-2013) then Outlook 'conveniently' increases the size of your text and images, but does so without truly scaling the whole email to the higher setting, which can royally screw up an email.

If the DPI scaling is your issue, I would use the above article and this recent SO question to hopefully solve your issue: [Prevent Images in HTML Email Scaling Up With DPI Scaling, Outlook 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31860828/prevent-images-in-html-email-scaling-up-with-dpi-scaling-outlook-2013)

Below is info pulled from SO answer above:

**Use inline styles and px units on tables.**
You'll want to define the height using the attribute, for Gmail. Then define the height and width inline, using px. Tables that have a percentage-based width don't need any treatment, as they scale well already.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td height="500" style="width: 500px;height: 500px;">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Add this to your code to make VML scale.**

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">

<head>
<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
  <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
    <o:AllowPNG/>
    <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
  </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
</xml><![endif]-->
</head>
```

**Use MSO Magic for cellspacing and cellpadding.**

Using these inline styles will allow you to create scalable cellspacing and cellpadding.

```
<table cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10" style="mso-cellspacing: 10px; mso-padding-alt: 10px 10px 10px 10px">
...
</table>
```

Below is the code with the validation error fixed:

```
<!-- Start Info Box -->
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="532" style="border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: none;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="padding-top: 20px;">
                            <img src="http://purolatorforsmallbusiness.com/content/acquisition/onboarding/infotab-top.png" alt="" height="7" width="532" style="border: 0;outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; display: block;">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: none;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="3" style="border-left:2px solid #00A9E0;border-right:2px solid #00A9E0;text-align: center; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #001996; font-size: 20px; font-weight: 700; line-height: 22px; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 10px;">
                                        Have a Q that needs an A?
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td width="250" height="30" style="padding-left:10px;border-left:2px solid #00A9E0;font-weight: 700; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height: 15px;color:black;vertical-align:bottom;padding-bottom:10px; padding-left: 25px;">
                                            Shipping help:
                                        </td>
                                        <td valign="bottom" align="center" width="2" rowspan="3" style="padding-left: 30px; padding-right: 30px;">
                                        <img src="http://purolatorforsmallbusiness.com/content/acquisition/onboarding/vertical-line.png" alt="|" height="80%" width="1" style="border: 0;outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; display: block;"></td>
                                        <td width="250" height="30" style="padding-left:10px;border-right:2px solid #00A9E0;font-weight: 700; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height: 15px;color:black;vertical-align:bottom;padding-bottom:10px;">
                                            Account questions:
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="padding-left:25px;border-left:2px solid #00A9E0;vertical-align:top;" class="temp-borders">
                                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse; -ms-text-size-adjust: none;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; padding-bottom: 20px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="padding-right: 5px; padding-bottom: 1px;">
                                                <img src="http://purolatorforsmallbusiness.com/content/acquisition/onboarding/phone.png" alt="Phone" height="13" width="14" style="border: 0;outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; display: block;">
                                                </td>
                                                <td valign="bottom" style="font-weight: 400; line-height: 18px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; padding-bottom: 1px;">
                                                    1&nbsp;888&nbsp;SHIP-123
                                                </td>
                                                <td style="padding-right: 5px; padding-bottom: 1px;">
                                                <img src="http://purolatorforsmallbusiness.com/content/acquisition/onboarding/chat.png" alt="Chat" height="13" width="14" style="border: 0;outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; display: block;">
                                                </td>
                                                <td valign="bottom" style="font-weight: 400; line-height: 18px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; padding-bottom: 1px;">
                                                <a style="text-decoration:none; color: #000000;" href="http://purolator.force.com/PreChat?chatLanguage=EN" target="_blank">Live&nbsp;Chat</a>
                                                </td>
                                                                                            </tr>

                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="padding-right: 5px; padding-bottom: 1px;">
                                                    <img src="http://purolatorforsmallbusiness.com/content/acquisition/onboarding/email.png" alt="Email" height="10" width="14" style="border: 0;outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; display: block;">
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td valign="bottom" style="font-weight: 400; line-height: 18px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; padding-bottom: 1px;">
                                                    <a style="text-decoration:none; color: #000000;" href="mailto:customer.care@purolator.com" target="_blank">E-mail us</a>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td style="padding-right: 5px; padding-bottom: 1px;">
                                                <img src="http://purolatorforsmallbusiness.com/content/acquisition/onboarding/twitter.png" alt="Email" height="11" width="16" style="border: 0;outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; display: block;">
                                                </td>
                                                <td valign="bottom" style="font-weight: 400; line-height: 18px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; padding-bottom: 1px;">
                                                <a style="text-decoration:none; color: #000000;" href="https://twitter.com/PurolatorHelp/" target="_blank">Tweet us</a>
                                                </td>
                                                </tr>
                                        </table>
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="padding-left:10px;border-right:2px solid #00A9E0;vertical-align:top;">
                                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: none;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; padding-bottom: 20px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="padding-right: 5px; padding-bottom: 1px;">
                                                <img src="http://purolatorforsmallbusiness.com/content/acquisition/onboarding/phone.png" alt="Phone" height="13" width="14" style="border: 0;outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; display: block;">
                                                </td>
                                                <td valign="bottom" style="font-weight: 400; line-height: 18px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; padding-bottom: 1px;">
                                                    1&nbsp;855&nbsp;711&nbsp;7277&nbsp;(PBRP)
                                                </td>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="padding-right: 5px; padding-bottom: 1px;">
                                                    <img src="http://purolatorforsmallbusiness.com/content/acquisition/onboarding/email.png" alt="Email" height="10" width="14" style="border: 0;outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; display: block;">
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td valign="bottom" style="font-weight: 400; mso-line-height-rule:exactly; line-height: 18px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px;">
                                                    <a style="text-decoration:none; color: #000000;" href="mailto:businessrewards@purolator.com" target="_blank">E-mail us</a>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: none;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; border-left: 2px solid #00a9e0; border-right: 2px solid #00a9e0; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 1px; mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;-ms-text-size-adjust: none;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; margin: 0; font-size: 1px; mso-line-height-rule:exactly; line-height:1px; height:1px;">&nbsp;


                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="mso-line-height-rule:exactly;line-height:7px;height:7px;">
                            <img src="http://purolatorforsmallbusiness.com/content/acquisition/onboarding/infotab-bottom.png" alt="" height="7" width="532" style="border: 0;outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; display: block;">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td height="20">&nbsp;

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <!-- End Info Box -->
```

Comment: Thanks for fixing the validation error for me and the detailed response. However, it didn't fix the problem of the "E-mail us" text floating up when viewed in Outlook 2013. That appears to be a problem with line-height or something else . . .

Comment: The issue might be that Outlook ignores html/css width & height declarations on images sometimes. I see that the email icon is actually only 8px high, so it could be that. Have not had time to test it, but if it isn't that, check https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ and see if perhaps some of your CSS is not compatable with Outlook 2013.